# Ionic MediaPlugin. Pause/Stop not triggered for IOS if interrupted by external app notifications

Tags: ionic2, cordova-media-plugin

I am using [MediaPlugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/) and [MusicControl](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls/) to stream music in my ionic app. 
The music plays fine in the background but when the audio is interrupted by notifications from other apps, I couldn't able to resume the music. This issue is only for IOS. In android, it works as expected.

In android, the media plugin pause/stop callback is triggered when there is an interruption. I don't see these events are triggered for ios. How to get hold of the pause/stop event if there is an interruption for IOS? I couldn't able to find anything from the forums as well.

```
  const onStatusUpdate = (status) => {
                console.log("media plugin status",status);
                switch (status){
                    case this.media.MEDIA_STARTING:
                        console.log("Media starting..");
                        break;
                    case this.media.MEDIA_RUNNING:
                        console.log("Media running..");
                        break;
                    case this.media.MEDIA_STOPPED:
                        console.log("Media stopped..");
                        Player.isPlaying=false;
                        break;
                    case this.media.MEDIA_PAUSED:
                        console.log("Media paused..");
                        Player.isPlaying=false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("Unhandled media status!!");
                        break;
                }
            };
    Player.stream = this.media.create(Player.streamUrl,onStatusUpdate,onSuccess,onError);
```

posted the same questing in [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/mediaplugin-pause-stop-not-triggered-for-ios-if-interrupted-by-external-app-notifications/88397) as well.

Comment: is this ionic 1 or 2?

Comment: ionic 2 framework